# Grails, MySQL, Passing Query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Currently I am working with `grails` and `MySQL`. I create the domain class of user like this:

```
class User {
        String userName
        String password
        String fullName
        String toString(){
            "${fullName}"
        }
    static constraints = {
        fullName();
        userName(unique:true);
        password(password:true);
    }
}
```

While running the app grails will create a table user with structure

```
id           bigint(20)
version      bigint(20)
full_name    varchar(255)
password     varchar(255)
user_name    varchar(255)
```

But I want to create my own table structure like this

```
user_id      int(20)
full_name    varchar(255)
password     varchar(255)
user_name    varchar(255)
```

and I also want to know the controller and model structure so that I can pass the insert query dynamically .

Can anyone help me with a demo or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## to create you own table you use mapping .

### `Example`

```
class User {
    String fname
    String postCode

    static mapping = {
        table 'userTable'  //your custom table name if you want
        version false   //turnoff grails version
        id column:'UserId'
        firstName column: 'First_Name'   //first name column will be like this
        postCode type: 'text'  //default Grails varchar() but can make to text

        //or for id you can use composit key of your chioce for id or even a generator

       id composite: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    }
}
```

for more playing on what you are capabale of Refer this link [[ORM in GRAILS]](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

This mapping block will remove the "version" column, and change the id column to "user_id" and change the type to what you want:

```
static mapping = {
   id column: 'user_id', sqlType: 'int(20)'
   version false
}
```